# How to transfer data across pages in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, textbox

I am designing a page using asp.net. There are two pages named 'View Hotel' and 'Edit hotel'. When the admin views the list of hotels on the 'View Hotel' page and clicks on the Edit button there, the information of the Hotel like the Hotel ID has to be fetched by the 'Edit Hotel' page and displayed in the text boxes for Editing.

How do I go about doing it? How do I bind data in tables with the text boxes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your edit button click event ,

```
Response.Redirect("yourEditPageUrl.aspx?HotelID=" + YourHotelId );
```

In your Hotel Edit Page's Loading

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
         String myHotelID = Request.QueryString["HotelID"].ToString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can send it with query string or using session as well

for session you can use simply

```
Session["HotelID"] = 5; // whatever id there
```

then access like

```
int _hotelID = (int)Session["HotelID"];
```

for query string

```
response.ridrect("HotelEdit.apsx?HotelID=" + value);
```

value is HotelID

Retrieve at Edit Hotel Page

```
string _HotelID = Request.QueryString["HotelID"].ToString();
```